# Do Gandharvas have legs? Especially Nalakuvara and Manigriva?

Tags: gandharva

Do Gandharvas have legs? especially Nalakuvara and Manigriva?

In the pictures where Krishna relieves them from the curse of being trees, they dont have legs as in many pictures.

Do all gandharvas don't have legs or it is just in that lila, gandharvas coming out of trees, they are depicted so?

In summary I want to know whether Nalakuvara and Manigriva had legs or not?

Comment: Why would you think that they won't have legs? Sure, they have supernatural abilities. But why would you think that Celestial Singers might be devoid of any body?

Comment: they may or even may not. Want to confirm from sastric text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well sharing an excerpt from a story involving **Nalakuvara**  as has been stated here on [wisdomlib](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424792.html) which shows that he had feet:

> Thus did she address Dashagriva, who answered her in smooth accents,
> saying:—
>
> You have said you are my daughter-in-law! For those who have but one
> husband, this argument is valid but in Devaloka, the Gods have
> established a law that is said to be eternal, that Apsaras have no
> appointed consorts nor are the Gods monogamous!
>
> Thus speaking, the Rakshasa, who had stationed himself on the mountain
> ridge, inflamed with desire, ravished Rambha and, when she was
> released from his embrace, her garlands and her ornaments spoiled and
> torn away, she resembled a river where a great elephant, disporting
> himself, muddying the waters, has borne away the banks. Her hair in
> disorder, her hands clenched, like unto a creeper with its flowers
> shaken by the wind, trembling with terror, **she sought out Nalakuvara
> and, with joined palms, fell at his feet.**
>
> Then he enquired of her saying:—
> 'What is this, O Blessed One? **Why dost you prostrate thyself at my feet?**'

Comment: thanks . that answers the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a verse which proves that gandharvas (especially Nalakūvara and Maṇigrīva) have legs

> [ŚB 10.10.6](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/10/6/)
>
> तं द‍ृष्ट्वा व्रीडिता देव्यो विवस्त्रा: शापशङ्किता: । वासांसि पर्यधु:
> शीघ्रं विवस्त्रौ नैव गुह्यकौ ॥ ६ ॥
>
> > Upon seeing Nārada, the naked young girls of the demigods were very
> > much ashamed. **Afraid of being cursed, they covered their bodies with
> > their garments. But the two sons of Kuvera did not do so; instead, not
> > caring about Nārada, they remained naked.**

---

Only when a Male has thighs/legs will they require to "cover" those areas with garments.